# is it possible to perform multiple payment operation in single transaction?

Tags: stellar-core, transactions, payments

**Scenario:**
when user pay(100%) on my website using my API in which I want to perform 2 payment operation 
 1. goes to production account(50% amount)
 2. goes to manager account (50% amount)

is this possible to achieve this in one trancation so that only one transaction hash is generated.

right now i am doing like this :4

> var productionPublickey =
>    'GDENPKUMUNAYWCRT7E6NFN5HBMNPIUISY7EJG4TVR3RHMS7FPQ2QJLZL';
>       StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();
>
> ```
> var managerPublickey = 'GAF2HC3YYBF2JPTQJO6NDVEGOR4RIFZ5VRKQ4AH5DQ6R75ZPHJB5VGGV'
> var account = await server.loadAccount(sourcePublicKey)
> var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
>     .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
>         destination: productionPublickey,
>         asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),//native asset lumen
>         amount: '50',
>     }))
>     .addMemo(StellarSdk.Memo.text('sent to production '))//optional 
>     .build();
> transaction.sign(sourceKeypair);
> const temp = await server.submitTransaction(transaction)
> console.log('submitted', temp._links);
>
>
>  account = await server.loadAccount(sourcePublicKey)
> var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
>     .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
>         destination: managerPublickey,
>         asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),//native asset lumen
>         amount: '50',
>     }))
>     .addMemo(StellarSdk.Memo.text('sent to manager'))//optional 
>     .build();
> transaction.sign(sourceKeypair);
> const temp2 = await server.submitTransaction(transaction)
>
>
> console.log('submitted', temp2._links);
>
>     res.send('sent')
> ```

Comment: Note that: "[If one operation is wrong then the whole transaction is wrong](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/if-one-operation-is-wrong-then-the-whole-transaction-is-wrong)"

Answer (score 7):

Sure, `addOperation` can be called multiple times.

```
const transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
  .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
    destination: managerPublickey,
    asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
    amount: '50',
  }))
  .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
    destination: managerPublickey,
    asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native()
    amount: '50',
  }))
  .addMemo(StellarSdk.Memo.text('Hello world!'))
  .build()
transaction.sign(sourceKeypair)
await server.submitTransaction(transaction)
```

You can only have one memo per transaction, though (which is why I think the method should be named `setMemo()`).

Comment: The transaction hash is generated is showing only one transacion when checked  on [here](http://testnet.stellarchain.io/tx/http://crypto-testnets.sofodev.co:8000/transactions/601a361e8289a840902dc619eed738d6556f23120ca11c1d3ef3445498525a06)

but both transaction is done sucessfully.
as i checked both account balances is incerment

Comment: Use https://stellar.expert instead.

Comment: Stellar uses CS nomenclature - a transaction is a single atomic operation on the ledger - as opposed to payments nomenclature where a transaction is a payment. You can kind-of think of a Stellar transaction as a batch, and a Stellar payment (or create account) operation as a transaction.