# If one operation is wrong then the whole transaction is wrong

Tags: horizon, transactions, operations

Found such a problem if one operation is wrong then the whole transaction is wrong.

```
ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\Horizon\Api\PostTransactionResponse Object
(
    [result:protected] => 
    [rawData:protected] => Array
        (
            [type] => https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed
            [title] => Transaction Failed
            [status] => 400
            [detail] => The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html
            [extras] => Array
                (
                    [envelope_xdr] => AAAAAG................................................==
                    [result_codes] => Array
                        (
                            [transaction] => tx_failed
                            [operations] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => op_success
                                    [1] => op_success
                                    [2] => op_malformed
                                    [3] => op_success
                                )

                        )

                    [result_xdr] => AAAAAAAAAZD/.....................................=
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is as per design.

> Operations are executed in order as one ACID transaction, meaning that either all operations are applied or none are. If any operation fails, the whole transaction fails.

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#list-of-operations

Comment: Is this not a horizon developer bug?

Comment: No. The transaction is atomic. All operations must succeed for the transaction to be accepted.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, as I understand it is necessary to check the response from transaction and if [transaction] => tx_failed, look for which operation is wrong

Comment: – Synesso, 
Maybe you know why **op_malformed** ? 
i make topic here https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/why-transaction-operation-op-malformed