# Why transaction operation "op_malformed"?

Tags: transactions, operations

As I understand "[If one operation is wrong then the whole transaction is wrong](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/if-one-operation-is-wrong-then-the-whole-transaction-is-wrong)"

Trying to find the cause 'op_malformed'

I already read it "[Transaction Malformed](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/errors/transaction-malformed.html)" 
I never found a mistake

This is operations [2] in transaction:

```
 [2] => ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Operation\ManageOfferOp Object
                    (
                        [sellingAsset:protected] => ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset Object
                            (
                                [type:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset:private] => 1
                                [assetCode:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset:private] => ****
                                [issuer:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset:private] => ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\AccountId Object
                                    (
                                        [accountIdString:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\AccountId:private] => **************************************HQ52
                                        [accountIdBytes:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\AccountId:private] => *********
                                        [keyType:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\AccountId:private] => 0
                                    )

                            )

                        [buyingAsset:protected] => ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset Object
                            (
                                [type:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset:private] => 0
                                [assetCode:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset:private] => 
                                [issuer:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset:private] => 
                            )

                        [amount:protected] => ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\Model\StellarAmount Object
                            (
                                [stroops:protected] => phpseclib\Math\BigInteger Object
                                    (
                                        [value] => 0x038d7ea42de980
                                        [engine] => internal (64-bit, OpenSSL)
                                    )

                                [stroopScaleBignum:protected] => phpseclib\Math\BigInteger Object
                                    (
                                        [value] => 0x00989680
                                        [engine] => internal (64-bit, OpenSSL)
                                    )

                                [maxSignedStroops64:protected] => phpseclib\Math\BigInteger Object
                                    (
                                        [value] => 0x7fffffffffffffff
                                        [engine] => internal (64-bit, OpenSSL)
                                    )

                            )

                        [price:protected] => ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Price Object
                            (
                                [numerator:protected] => 0.0004328
                                [denominator:protected] => 1
                            )

                        [offerId:protected] => 71480124
                        [sourceAccount:protected] => 
                        [type:protected] => 3
                    )
```

this is horizon response:

```
ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\Horizon\Api\PostTransactionResponse Object
(
    [result:protected] => 
    [rawData:protected] => Array
        (
            [type] => https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed
            [title] => Transaction Failed
            [status] => 400
            [detail] => The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html
            [extras] => Array
                (
                    [envelope_xdr] => *****************==
                    [result_codes] => Array
                        (
                            [transaction] => tx_failed
                            [operations] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => op_success
                                    [1] => op_success
                                    [2] => op_malformed
                                    [3] => op_success
                                )

                        )

                    [result_xdr] => AAAAAAAAAZD/////*****************=
                )

        )

)
```

maybe there is an error:

```
[buyingAsset:protected] => ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset Object
                            (
                                [type:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset:private] => 0
                                [assetCode:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset:private] => 
                                [issuer:ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Asset:private] => 
                            )
```

---

Many thanks to all for help in finding the error. @sui @Synesso

> The **price** in stellar is displayed as a **simple fraction** in
>   which you need to transfer your decimal, and publish it in the form:
>   numerator and denominator separately. **(int) numerator, (int)
>   denominator.**

I tested a lot of functions for finding the minimum fraction for converting from decimal, this is what I found / added (PHP code):

```
function float2fraction($n, $tolerance = 1.e-9) { 
/* www.mera.one, stellar price float2fraction function - return numerator / denominator */
    $n = (float) $n;
    $h1=1; $h2=0;
    $k1=0; $k2=1;
    $b = 1/$n;
    do {
        $b = 1/$b;
        $a = floor($b);
        $aux = $h1; $h1 = $a*$h1+$h2; $h2 = $aux;
        $aux = $k1; $k1 = $a*$k1+$k2; $k2 = $aux;
        $b = $b-$a;
    } while (abs($n-$h1/$k1) > $n*$tolerance);

    if ( ! empty ( $h1 ) && ! empty ( $k1 ))
        return array ( "nominator" => $h1, "denominator" => $k1, "str_view" => "$h1/$k1" ) ;
    else
        return false;
}
```

ps: I also received an error from the ZuluCrypto class "error code 3 in CreateAccountResult.php", adding this code to the $errorCodeMap program began to run.
In ZuluCrypto itself, it’s just about writing errors when working with floating point ("Floating point issues")

Comment: Please show us the value for `envelope_xdr`

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [stellar laboratory XDR viewer](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test) to debug it. You can get the transactions XDR representation with this method using zulucrypto/stellar-api php sdk:

```
echo base64_encode($txEnvelope->toXdr());
```

Comment: can you post the raw xdr output?

Answer (score 1):

The [result XDR](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAAAAAGT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwAAAAA%3D&type=TransactionResult&network=public), when decoded, shows the error is `manage_offer_malformed`. The description for this error is

> The input is incorrect and would result in an invalid offer.

The [transaction](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAGBHqzSmRfktqMhKQoeKjJHsUgUDegVG2YrcO1nXpDujAAAAZAFamwoAAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAMAAAABTUVSQQAAAABgR6s0pkX5LajISkKHioyR7FIFA3oFRtmK3DtZ16Q7owAAAAAN4LazpstpgAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAARm4sQAAAAAAAAAAdekO6MAAABALh%2FvU4QgNa0pJCdWXTxmfj8VytbzFT3DIw%2BtNJ%2BdmDX3APwxwqqEqIS3WAaZrllZRwif8q7XP0G%2FLrTpO%2F34Bg%3D%3D&type=TransactionEnvelope&network=public) has a price of `0/1`. This seems wrong.

Comment: Your price is wrong.   `[price:protected] => ZuluCrypto\StellarSdk\XdrModel\Price Object
                            (
                                [numerator:protected] => 0.0004328
                                [denominator:protected] => 1
                            )` numerator should be int, its rounded to 0 and thus is malformed. (this one: ´$mera_current_courses [ $val [ 'asset_code_b' ] ]´ )